# What is the best way to associate a thumbnail with an image in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, image, thumbnails

I am building a database for a website that will be a cataloge of products.
I am having a problem with the table of images. I have a php script that resizes the image with three sizes, renames them with a suffix, writes them to a directory and adds a reference to them in a table of images.

I am having trouble figuring out how the thumbnails (the small images) will be associated with the medium and large images since I'm planning to have multiple images for each product. I want to be able to add all thumbnails to a page with a link either to the medium or large image via a php script.

Here is what I have so far,

```
image-id  product-id  filename              size    caption  width  height  alt
13        1           PassPro150_large.jpg  large   NULL     632    569     NULL
14        1           PassPro150_medium.jpg medium  NULL     250    225     NULL
15        1           PassPro150_small.jpg  small   NULL     115    103     NULL
```

Is there a standard way to do this? Should I make three tables, one for each size and associate them with a primary-foreign key? I also thought I could do it with string manipulation, replace _small with _large since all images uploaded will have the same postfix. Any suggestions?

Comment: another column perhaps `thumbnail-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Joseph said is one solution.
Or you could create multiple folders different sizes of thumbnails, like thumb_small, thumb_medium and save the images in there with same name.

You just keep the filename in the database. and when you need to display the image you adjust the url to the particular folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that is one solution, but then I lose the size data.

Comment: Although I suppose I could record all three sets of dimensions in the same row.

Comment: maintaining separate folders is additional overhead. i suggest keeping them in one folder (saves you the hassle of creating folders using PHP) and use a better filename scheme

Comment: @Joseph You dont create the folders using PHP. You create them beforehand.

Rob Fenwick aren't the sizes predefined!! If you are talking about the original size, then like you said you can keep them in the database itself. You dont need multiple rows for the same image, record the original size in the same row and fetch the required sized image from the respective folder with same filename.

Comment: No they will all be different sizes, the images are resized by area for the large and small images and resized to a specific width on the medium image, but the heights will still vary. But so far it seems like your solution is the simplest, I could have columns for width_small, height_small, width_medium, height_medium, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why to use a database **for this purpose** at all.

Can't you just add a word "small" to the image name and put it in the img tag, along with predefined dimensions?

Comment: Because I don't want to have to make a page for each product, I will have one php script that will create all the pages for all the products. About 50 products.

Comment: It seems you can't get the context of your own question. Edited my answer to make it more clear for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am not understanding your point. How does a php script find an image and connect it to a product without a database?

Comment: you can name your files after product id and/or store them in the folder named after product id.

Comment: But there will be multiple images for each product, so I still don't understand how that could work.

Comment: You can store multiple files in the folder, can't you?

Comment: Of course, but not with the same name, if I name the all the image files associated with a particular product with the product id.

Comment: As I said above, **or store them in the folder named after product id**. It is not a big deal though to distinguish the files even named after id. A programmer would solve such a problem in a second.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create one table for recording the images.
2. once you upload the images, rename the image to correspond to the item ID
3. to add to that, append also what image number it is
4. use a PHP script to resize your images and append as a suffix the size

now you will have this format:

```
imageid_imagenumber_imagesize.jpg
```

where:

- imageid - corresponds to the item id
- imagenumber - to distinguish it from the other images of the same product
- imagesize - the suffix of the size

place them somewhere in your website, and you are good to go. no need for a database

as for image dimensions, and other meta data about the image, read more about [getting the  EXIF data using PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

Comment: The images don't have predefined sizes, as some are wider in the horizontal dimension and some are larger in the vertical dimension. The php script resizes the large and small by a specified area, the medium by width but the height varies.

Comment: I already have a suffix, _small _medium and _large, the plan is to have a php script that finds all thumbnails for a particular product, without me having to do anything, and link to the large or medium image, but the problem is how to get the script to link to the right large image.

Comment: updated my answer. now there is totally no use for a database.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I don't see how when an image is uploaded the php script that renames the image will know which number to add to the the suffix, how will the script know how many if any have already been uploaded? And how will the script that writes the page be able to get all the images for a particular product? They won't all have the same number of images. Do I use a wildcard or something in the filename? And if so (although I'm not sure if that is even possible) it seems that I am back to the same problem of associating the thumbnail with the correct image.